# Nested Html Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following straightforward razor code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BusinessName, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BusinessName, new { @class = "form-control" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BusinessName)
      </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to wrap this all in a custom html helper, however, when reading about creating your own, I don't see how I would pass in the existing 'TextBoxFor' and 'ValidationMessageFor' helpers to the custom html helper constructor that I will be creating. Is there a way to do this, or will I be better looking at the output of the helpers I want to nest and create the necessary tags manually within my custom helper?

Comment: Why do want to go for a custom helper instead you could use the display template to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass in an expression that returns the property of your model that you are using within the helper. From there, you can use `TagBuilder` objects to construct your desired HTML.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString FormGroup<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var labelFor = html.LabelFor(expression);
        var textBoxFor = html.TextBoxFor(expression);
        var validationMessageFor = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression);

        var innerDivWrapper = new TagBuilder("div");
        innerDivWrapper.AddCssClass("col-sm-6");
        innerDivWrapper.InnerHtml = textBoxFor.ToHtmlString() + validationMessageFor.ToHtmlString();

        var wrapperTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
        wrapperTagBuilder.AddCssClass("form-group");
        wrapperTagBuilder.InnerHtml = labelFor.ToHtmlString() + innerDivWrapper;

        return new MvcHtmlString(wrapperTagBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Your extension method must take two type parameters: `TModel` to know what your model type is, and `TValue` to know the type returned by the expression.

The method is used like this within your Razor template:

```
@Html.FormGroup(x => x.City)
```

As Venkat pointed out in his comment, this would probably be better achieved through a display template, but this will get the job done as described in the question.